# Regex exceptions to introduce in array of values

Tags: java, regex

i have created regular expression like this:

```
^[0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][a-z]_([0-9]{1,10})_([0-9]{1,11})_([0-9]{1,11})$
```

It should give me values range from  01BRa_1_1_1 to 99BRz_9999999999_99999999999_99999999999

My problem is that I need to exclude values 0 from _number_number_number and to start from number 1. 
Have been trying different expressions but can't find right one.

If someone knows how to solve thi help will be good. thx.

Goal is to eliminate 0_0_0 and also 00_00_00 and also 000_000_000 and all situations where 0 is first number so the first combination would be 1_1_1 for those 3 fields.

I am using this in Java (to reply to one comment) but do not see relevance of that more or less this is just a Pattern.

Resolved with this:

```
^[0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][a-z]_([1-9][0-9]{0,9})_([1-9][0-9]{0,10})_([1-9][0-9]{0,10})$
```

Comment: Some examples of exclusions would help

Comment: Indeed - there are many numbers there

Comment: So you're saying you want this: `^[0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][a-z]_([1-9]{1,10})_([1-9]{1,11})_([1-9]{1,11})$`?

Comment: @nattyddubbs - I think the issue is that would exclude `99BRz_10_10_10`, which should be legal.

Comment: @AshwinMukhija - I believe the OP is trying to exclude `_0_0_0`, `_00_00_00`, `_000_000_000`, etc. More example would certainly clarify things, though.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 Its amazing now different people can interpret especially when there are no examples ;-)

Comment: @nattyddubbs - True true.

Comment: The tool or language is extremely important. Different "flavors" support different features. Java supports much more than javascript, for example, and Perl and .NET support way more then Java.

Comment: nice, tidier: ^\d\dBR[a-z]_([1-9]\d{0,9})_([1-9]\d{0,10})_([1-9]\d{0,10})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to eliminate values equal to 0 (0, 00, 000, etc) then an expression like this might work:

```
^[0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][a-z]_(?!0+_)([0-9]{1,10})_(?!0+_)([0-9]{1,11})_(?!0+$)([0-9]{1,11})$
```

Of course, this will depend on your regex engine supporting variable-length zero-width assertions (aka "lookahead"). It would help to know which flavor you are using. (From the [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) tooltip: *"Please also include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using."*)

If your goal is to eliminate anything starting with 0, (0, 01, 001, etc), then an expression like this might work:

```
^[0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][a-z]_([1-9][0-9]{0,10})_([1-9][0-9]{0,10})_([1-9][0-9]{0,10})$
```

Comment: the first one solves my problem. t I still need to cover cases like 01_01_01 or 0something_0something_0something

Comment: manage to cover for example 00_00_00 with (?!00+_). It will be long expression to cover all cases with starting 0 for all 3 fields. If there is some expression to cover all cases from one 0 to 11 zeroes that will be full solution

Comment: @Akosha - the `+` after the zero means it will match one or more zeroes until it encounters an `_`. `(?!0+_)` should handle `0_`, `00_`, `000_`, ad infinitum.

Comment: I know but somehow it does not. But the other solution working fine for me. This is more elegant but does not do what I need...

Comment: Validating *numbers* with regular expressions is a *bad* idea.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse - Thanks for your opinion. I will gladly upvote a simpler, more elegant solution, if you care to provide one.